# Are solar panel films for windows ready for the end users?

Tags: electrical, solar-panels

I read about a new solar-panel technology, based on a photo-sensible film, which may be applied directly on to glass.

This will definitely help in the versatility and in the ease of installation..

Are any of you aware of this technology? Did you ever see it in use?

some references:

[commercial product?](http://www.newenergytechnologiesinc.com/technology/solarwindow)

[3m solar films](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Renewable/Energy/Product/Films/)

Answer (score 3):

Photovoltaic windows are not commercially available. Most examples of this idea, including the SolarWindow to which you linked, are made of organic photovoltaic (OPV) materials. OPV is, compared to other PV technologies, in a very early stage of development. Laboratory cells still have quite low efficiency and very short lifetimes compared to more mature PV technologies.

The 3M solar films you linked to are barrier, backsheet, encapsulant and reflector films. They are made as *components* of solar panels and they do not produce electricity.